# How to avoid sticky ALT key on Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11

I'm facing this weird issue on Windows 11: sometimes, looks like my ALT key is being pressed without me pressing it. My keyboard stops working properly: for instance, if I type the 'D' key, actually Windows understands ALT+D. Any key I type is interpreted as this key plus ALT.

Usually, when this happens, I reboot the machine and it goes back to work normally.

What is happening here?

Comment: Laptop or Desktop ? Can you try a different keyboard?

Comment: Laptop, problem is not the keyboard, i've been thru this same issues on different keyboards act ually. Looks like is related to some Windows configuration

Comment: I have Windows 11 (and since the beginning) and on different machines. No issue with Windows 11 as far as I can see. Try manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all Drivers

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + Alt + Del (ESC to exit the screen) does it get unstuck (at least for a while)? Alternatively, press the two Crtl keys and release, does that help?

Comment: Other options that can help are pressing the FN (if available) key or combinations of pressing Crtl/Alt/Shift/(FN) simultaneously.

Comment: Temp., to see if it has any effect, you could try to disable the Crtl Key (e.g. via Powertoys, SharpKeys, etc.). Also make sure Sticky Keys are off: Windows-Settings -> Accessibility -> Keyboard -> Sticky keys

Comment: I've edited the question, because actually is not CTRL, but ALT , the bugged key

Comment: @Albin When i keep pressing ALT key, it seems to fix the issue without having to reboot, thanks for the hint. Still, i'm curious why this happens.

Comment: @delphirules mostly due to drivers or software interfacing with the keyboard (eg. autokey etc.), often an update helps.

Comment: @delphirules I added an answer, a checkmark and/or upvote would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem, usually due to poor software like drivers etc., there are a few solutions available that often work:

First of all disable Sticky Keys: Windows-Settings -> Accessibility -> Keyboard -> Sticky keys

- Try pressing Alt key once and/or multiple times
- Try pressing Ctrl + Alt + Del (ESC to exit the screen)
- Try pressing FN Key
- Try pressing combinations of Crtl/Alt/Shift/(FN) eg.g Crtl+Alt, Crtl+Alt+Shift, etc.

Temp., to see if it has any effect, you could try to disable the Crtl Key (e.g. via Powertoys, SharpKeys, etc.).

There are different cases to this problem, mostly software related e.g. when the operating system does not notice the release of a control key. For example, a badly written driver for some hardware which causes a delay during which Windows skips the detection of the release of the key. This is usually rather hard to troubleshoot.

I would suggest updating starting with drivers and work your way up to the software your are using.